# Why mysql rows showing 0-3 out of 4?

Tags: mysql, datatable

**Why this is happening and how to get rid of it?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXohu.png)

Why there is showing rows 0-3 when total rows is 4

Comment: Because it's indexed from 0. So first row is at index 0 and fourth is at index 3

Answer (score -1):

In computer science master, the basis for starting numbers is zero, not one.
Count from 0 to 3 to get to 4.

Be sure to read this link and there are many like this link on the internet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering